Typescript react-vite/socket.io avatar chat structure confusion
I'm currently working on a avatar chat game using Typescript express/socket.io for the backend and Typescript react-vite/socket.io-client for the frontend.
For the authentication I'm using a axios post to a backend route which returns a JWT token for authentication. Once the user authenticated I store data in the local-storage which is used to send the user ID with the socket connection to establish a socket connection.
In the backend the users which are connected are stored inside a GameManager class. The structure in the backend looks like this:
game =>
    config => 
        room.config.ts
    interfaces =>
        IClientPlayerData.ts
        IClientRoomData.ts
        IClientRoomJoinData.ts
        IGameManager.ts
        IPlayerManager.ts
        IPlayerPosition.ts
        IRoomManager.ts
    manager =>
        game.manager.ts
        player.manager.ts
        room.manager.ts
    server.ts


The GameManager class is responsible for managing the rooms and the players by storing objects of connected players (PlayerManager objects) and rooms (RoomManager objects).
The PlayerManager class is responsible for managing the player data (id, username, position, room, socket).
The RoomManager class is responsible for managing the room data (id, name, description, participants, capacity, status).

The client structure looks like the following:
game =>
    context =>
        GameContext.tsx
    interfaces => 
        IGameInterface.ts
        IPlayerInterface.ts
        IPlayerPosition.ts
        IRoomInterface.ts
        IRoomOverviewInterface.ts
    manager =>
        player.manager.ts
        room.manager.ts
        room.overview.manager.ts


The GameContext is responsible for managing the game state and the socket connection.
The PlayerManager is responsible for managing the player data (id, username, position, room).
The RoomManager is responsible for managing the room the user currently is in data (id, name, participants).
The RoomOverviewManager is responsible for managing the room overview data (id, name, description, participant_count, user_capacity, status).

Once the user connects through a socket, the backend sends a list of rooms to store in the frontend. Its used to display available rooms to join to the user. Once the user selected a room it will send a request to the server using socket.emit. The backend will now deliver a updated room overview object to all connected players updating the existing overview (Setting a updated participant_count to the room). The user will now receive a extra emit message containing (id, name, participants) data of a room he selected to join. Inside the event listener in GameContext.tsx the room data will be assigned by creating a object using the room.manager.ts.
Now the user will see a canvas object which is supposed to be used in the future to draw a room UI on and display connected users avatars. I do not know how to continue now. Should the canvas.tsx view now be used to handle all the game functions like drawing users, sending emit data to the server containing messages and position updates or should a new class be created doing this stuff using the existing player / room objects?
Extra information: Every backend call like database related stuff will be done using API calls. The socket.io functionality should only contain the following:
Position updates sending and receiving, message sending and receiving, join and leave data
File overview for the client: gist.github.com
What would be the way to continue at this point?

...what's your actual question? "What would be the way to continue at this point?" is extremely vague. Do you have a specific question about your actual code and/or architecture that can be objectively answered (i.e. is a matter fact and not opinion)? As for the bit about canvas, you should separate the bits related to presentation of data to the user and the bits that perform logic on that data. Note that advice is an opinion (albeit a very common and well-respected one) and as such not really suitable for SO...
